# Determine if Values of Columns are within other Columns

Tags: r

I have several data frames with three columns, is it a possible to create a function that determines when the `.pe` column is within the corresponding `.lo` and `.up` columns. As well as when the `.lo` value is less than zero and the `.up` value is greater than zero. I have already created subsets of the original data frame so a function for each would work, unless it is possible to do this on a larger scale. Below is an example of one dataframe.

```
             x.pe          x.lo         x.up
1               0 -1.520961e-12 3.329460e-12
2               0 -2.891532e-14 9.583938e-03
3               0 -3.431072e-12 7.160141e-13
4               0 -1.367898e-13 6.254533e-13
5               0 -2.350169e-14 5.177390e-13
6               0 -2.693667e-15 2.453846e-14
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Based on the below responses, I was able to create the function:

```
within.function <- function(x){
  x <- x %>% mutate(
    pe_within_lo_up = x[,1] > x[,2] & x[,1] < x[,3],
    pe_within_lo_up = between(x[,1], x[,2], x[,3]), ## another way to do it
    lo_neg_hi_pos = x[,2] < 0 & x[,3] > 0)
  return(list(which(x$pe_within_lo_up == F), which(x$lo_neg_hi_pos == T)))
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what similar SO posts have you looked at as research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. Here' some to get you started. I'll assume your data is called `d`.

```
# base R version:
d$pe_within_lo_up = with(d, x.pe > x.lo & x.pe < x.up)
d$lo_neg_up_pos = with(d, x.lo < 0 & x.up > 0)

# dplyr version
library(dplyr)
d %>% mutate(
  pe_within_lo_up = x.pe > x.lo & x.pe < x.up,
  pe_within_lo_up = between(x.pe, x.lo, x.up), ## another way to do it
  lo_neg_up_pos = x.lo < 0 & x.up > 0
)
```

Here's a function that looks for column names with pattern `.pe`, `.lo` and `.up` and does this on them. It will probably error or behave unexpectedly if multiple columns in the same data frame meet these patterns.

```
foo = function(d) {
  lo = grep(".lo", names(d), fixed = TRUE)
  up = grep(".up", names(d), fixed = TRUE)
  pe = grep(".pe", names(d), fixed = TRUE)

  d$pe_within_lo_up = d[[pe]] > d[[lo]] & d[[pe]] < d[[up]]
  d$lo_up_cross_0 = d[[lo]] < 0 & d[[up]] > 0

  return(d)
}

## demo on Duck's nicely shared data:
foo(df)
#   x.pe          x.lo         x.up pe_within_lo_up lo_up_cross_0
# 1    0 -1.520961e-12 3.329460e-12            TRUE          TRUE
# 2    0 -2.891532e-14 9.583938e-03            TRUE          TRUE
# 3    0 -3.431072e-12 7.160141e-13            TRUE          TRUE
# 4    0 -1.367898e-13 6.254533e-13            TRUE          TRUE
# 5    0 -2.350169e-14 5.177390e-13            TRUE          TRUE
# 6    0 -2.693667e-15 2.453846e-14            TRUE          TRUE
```

Comment: Would it be possible to turn this into a function so that I can apply this across several dataframes?

Comment: Do all the data frames have the same column names? Or do you need to specify which columns to check when you call the function?

Comment: Yes, they all have `.pe`, `.lo`, and `.up`

Comment: So... not the same, but same pattern. One might be `x.pe`, another might be `y.pe`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've started a function by indexing each column but was hoping for something more concrete to determine when each variable is between the `.lo` and `.up` and if `.lo` and `.up` cross zero.

Comment: Thanks, I used something similar to both Duck and Gregor Thomas, I made the result provide a list of where the answers were true or false based on what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Try this built-in function using `base R`, you can apply directly to your dataframes:

```
#Function
myfun <- function(x)
{
  x$between <- ifelse(x$x.pe>=x$x.lo & x$x.pe<=x$x.up,1,0)
  x$less <- ifelse(x$x.pe<0,1,0)
  x$greater <- ifelse(x$x.pe>0,1,0)
  return(x)
}
#Apply
myfun(df)
```

Output:

```
  x.pe          x.lo         x.up between less greater
1    0 -1.520961e-12 3.329460e-12       1    0       0
2    0 -2.891532e-14 9.583938e-03       1    0       0
3    0 -3.431072e-12 7.160141e-13       1    0       0
4    0 -1.367898e-13 6.254533e-13       1    0       0
5    0 -2.350169e-14 5.177390e-13       1    0       0
6    0 -2.693667e-15 2.453846e-14       1    0       0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(x.pe = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x.lo = c(-1.520961e-12, 
-2.891532e-14, -3.431072e-12, -1.367898e-13, -2.350169e-14, -2.693667e-15
), x.up = c(3.32946e-12, 0.009583938, 7.160141e-13, 6.254533e-13, 
5.17739e-13, 2.453846e-14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```